# Scope of variable in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, variables

I have a doubt in finding the scope of a variable. Yes, I know about the scope concept but what my question is "Is there any shortcut exists for finding the scope of a variable in Android Studio?".

Shortcuts like `CTRL+P` is used for **parameter query** and `CTRL+Q` is used for **Documentation query**.

In a similar way *(not only keyboard shortcuts)*, is there any simple way to find the scope of a particular variable rather than going through the whole code.

You may wonder, is it really a problem?. But in my case I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to reach a variable declaration with a shortcut is

> CTRL+B

It doesn't really give scope of the variable, but jumps to the declaration